# iTerm window highlighted on the current line

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm

[image: Screenshot of iTerm showing highlight on current line]

I do not understand why the active terminal command line is highlighted. I am using iTerm2 and also have zsh and oh-my-zsh installed, but even after disabling them I still see this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is an iTerm option which can be enabled or disabled using the "View > Show Cursor Guide" menu item, or with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⎇</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>.